# Can we export reducer through named export from the slice in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm exporting my reducer through named export from the slice but its not receiving properly in the store and I see the following errors

`No reducer provided for key "cart"`

`Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.`.
Although, it was working when done through default export.
Here is my code:

**cartSlice.js:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    add(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    addAll(state, action) {
      return [...state, ...action.payload];
    },
    remove(state, action) {
      state = state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { add, addAll, remove } = cartSlice.actions;
export const {cartReducer} = cartSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js:**

```
import { cartReducer } from "./cartSlice";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart: cartReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

**Note:** It's a complex concept to understand for the beginners, so be polite, and instead of down-grading the question, please try to elaborate the concept in simple words.

Comment: You could create a named reducer function and export *that*, like your answer below, but probably better to stick to established conventions and default export the reducer function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a slightly different approach, just removed the curly braces {} in the export statement and the error was gone.

```
export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;
```